# Android Initial Login Screen then use fragments to swipe between screens once login is successful

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android app, then has an initial login screen that detects if a user is Admin or User. Once logged in, the user (depending on their role) will see different tabs to swipe between. I have a basic app that starts with a login activity and the login to decipher the users roles (using static values for now). First part is ok. Now when I try to use Fragments after the login screen, I'm getting stuck.

```
I have a LoginActivity that has an onClikcListener on a button after user enters credentials. Depending on whether the user is Amin or General Users, it will just to a new activity either activity_vote_admin or activity_vote_user. At this point I am stuck. Any ideas if what I am trying to do is valid. Or is there a better way to do this. At the moment I am getting this error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild/com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild.activity_vote_admin}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference.

LoginActivity (this is my main activity)
...
package com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static EditText username;
    private static EditText password;
    public static TextView attempts;
    private static Button submit_button;
    int attempt_counter = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginButton();

    }

    public void loginButton() {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        attempts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Attempts);


        //Reference button view
        final Button submit_button = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        // perform click event on button
        submit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onClick(View v) {

                                                 if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                                                         password.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                                                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome " + username.getText(),
                                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                     Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, activity_vote_admin.class);
                                                     startActivity(intent);
                                                 } else if (username.getText().toString().equals("user") &&
                                                         password.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                                                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome " + username.getText(),
                                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                     Intent intentUser = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, activity_vote_user.class);
                                                     startActivity(intentUser);

                                                 } else {
                                                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User or Password incorrect",
                                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                     attempt_counter--;
                                                     attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                                                     if (attempt_counter == 0) {

                                                         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Too many failed attempts, please close app and try again",
                                                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         submit_button.setEnabled(false);
                                                     }

                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }
        );
    }
}

...

Activity_vote_admin

...

package com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class activity_vote_admin extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Field for selecting the number of confidence votes
     */
    RatingBar mResults;
    private RatingBar rBar;
    Button mBtn;

    /**
     * Spinner field to enter the project name
     */
    private Spinner mProjectSpinner;

    /**
     * Projects. The possible values are:
     * stored locally - Needs to get values from a database. TODO
     */
    int mProject = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_vote_main_admin);

            // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

            // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
            AdminFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new AdminFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set the adapter onto the view pager
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            // initiate a rating bar
            rBar = findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
            //float vote = rBar.getRating();

            // Find all relevant views for user input
            mResults = findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);

            mProjectSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_project);

            // Run getRating method to get rating number from a rating bar
            //getRating();

            // Initiate button
            mBtn = findViewById(R.id.voteButton);

            // perform click event on button
            mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get values and then displayed in a toast
                    //String totalStars = "Total Stars:: " + RatingBar.getNumStars();
                    float vote = rBar.getRating();
                    String rating = "Rating : " + vote;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rating + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            projectSpinner();
        }

        // Setup the dropdown spinner that allows the user to select the role.

        private void projectSpinner() {
            // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
            // the spinner will use the default layout
            ArrayAdapter projectSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.projects, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
            projectSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

            // Apply the adapter to the project spinner
            mProjectSpinner.setAdapter(projectSpinnerAdapter);


            // Set the integer mSelected to the constant values
            mProjectSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    if(mProjectSpinner.getSelectedItem() == "This is Hint Text");

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                        if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.nextGEMS1_5))) {
                            mProject = 0 ;
                            return;
                        } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.nextGEMS1_6))) {
                            mProject = 1;
                            return;
                        } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.nextGEMS1_7))) {
                            mProject = 2;
                            return;
                        } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.nextGEMS1_8))) {
                            mProject = 3;
                            return;
                        } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.nextGEMS1_9))) {
                            mProject = 4;
                            return;
                        }
                        else mProject = 0;
                    }
                }

                // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    mProject = 0; // User
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ...

    activity_vote_main_admin.xml
    ...

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:name="com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild.testFragment1"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    ...
    activity_login.xml

    ...
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#5fb0c9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="450dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon"
                            android:hint="User Name"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:maxLines="1" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:maxLines="1" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Forgot Password?" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="22dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/action_buttom"
                        android:text="Sign in"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/attempts_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingTop="1dp"
                            android:text="Number of attempts remaining: " />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_Attempts"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingTop="1dp"
                            android:text="5" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lnkRegister"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="30dp"
                        android:text="Register here"
                        android:textColor="#5fb0c9"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/conferencevote_logo"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:src="@drawable/confvotenew"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    ...

    AdminFragemntyPagerAdapter
    ...
    package com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild;

    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    public class AdminFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public AdminFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new testFragment1();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new testFragment2();
            } else {
                return new testFragment2();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    ...

aactivity_vote_user.xml

...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#5fb0c9"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vote_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="USER VOTE"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vote_title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="450dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="70dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_project"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                        android:hint="@string/spinner_hint"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/attCobalt"
                        android:popupBackground="@color/myBlue"
                        android:dropDownSelector="@color/attBlue"

                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stepSize="1.0"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:theme="@style/rating_bar"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Vote and Submit" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/voteButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/action_buttom"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/conferencevote_logo"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:src="@drawable/confvotenew"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    ...

My fragments are as follows.
...
package com.example.confidencevotefragmentrebuild;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class testFragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_vote_user, container, false);


    }


}
...
```

Comment: Please add layout where you have declare voteButton in xml

Answer (score 0):

There are two reason for this issue :

1. You didn't declare any button on "activity_vote_main_admin.xml", thats why your view not binding with activity and giving null pointer exception.
2. May be you declare the button on fragment xml and trying to bind it with activity.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, What I forgot to add is that I have another xml file named activity_vote_admin.xml that has teh button and the page layout defined but my  viewpager is being setup on the activity_vote_main, which is called via the activity_vote_admin class. I do nto know where to place the pageviewer as I need to have eh spinner and rating bar loaded into a fragement. Perhaps I am trying to do this the wrong way ? I think I need to take my ratingbar and spiiner out of teh avtivity_vote_user class and palce this somewhere else. ? Does that make sense ?

Comment: I have updated my code snipet aboove to include teh XML fiel contain the layout and button and also one of my fragemtns classes.

Comment: I have progressed slightly. I have placed my spinner and rating bar activities into one of eht fragements but Im not seeing another error. "Method does not overide methed in superclass" on my onCreateView method. I do not think I can add this to my fragement. I fi can what is the work around ? If I cannot how or what is teh best way to have a fragement load a new view that has button clicks within the fragment ?

Comment: @JamesBampton focus on basic thing. Don't make it complicated. Just remember one thing Particular View class(Fragment or Activity) only can bind define xml  view. You can achieve whatever you want using fragment. And no need to create another view for button click. Use same fragment for button click.
For this error "Method does not override method in superclass" you need to check override method, Remember Don't copy activity method to fragment for better practice.